# PHP - How to update table using auto increment (value++)

Tags: php, mysql

someone can tell me how to update the value from 0 to 1, 52 to 53 (value++) using php script?
i want to search it on go*gle but i dunno the keyword to find it

[image: database.png]

Comment: which row you wanna update?

Comment: You want a query to increment or you are looking for a PHP Script for incrementing the values?

Comment: why you just turn auto increment in the structure settings on?

Comment: Do you want to increase the `id` column? OR any other column?

Comment: i want to update 5_sangat_baik, 4_baik, 3_cukup, 4_buruk, 5_sangat_buruk, but depending on the user which script he/she want to access

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update one column, for example `5_sagnat_baik` - just run the query:

```
UPDATE `question` SET `5_sagnat_baik` = `5_sagnat_baik` + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"UPDATE table_name
 SET column_name = column_name+ 1
 WHERE condition";
```

Hope this help

Comment: [Please stop using mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), as they have been removed from PHP

Answer (score 1):

You may update your auto-increment column (known as 'id') using a "update" sql in your php script using something like:

```
'UPDATE table_name SET id=(id + 1), [column2]=[value2], ...'
```

OR with PHP computed values (here $current_value):

```
'UPDATE table_name SET id=' . $current_value + 1 ', [column2]=[value2], ...'
```

The SQL update request is explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_update.asp (or here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/update/#syntax)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, here [we do not like W3schools links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) but otherwise, great answer. :)

Comment: @4796321 oh ok. Here is the SQL update reference then: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/update/#syntax (I have edited the answer in consequence).